# How to raise own error when one argument is missing?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

Hi I'm pretty new to Python and I've just started to learn about errors and exceptions.I have this function in a class that inserts a line at a given index called num.I know python will raise an error if no num is given but I want to raise my own error.How do I do that?This is what I tried. But the error raised is still the default error?

```
 def insertNum(self, num, line):
    if num== None:
        raise Exception("Num not specified.")
    else:
        self.list.insert(num, line)
    return self.list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try...except` statement.

```
def insertNum(num, line):
   try:
     list.insert(num, line)
     return list
   except:
     print('custom error')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value of `num` to `None` and then check if the value is `None`.

```
def insertNum(self, line, num=None):
    if num is None:
        raise Exception("Num not specified.")
    else:
        self.list.insert(num, line)
    return self.list
```

If you pass only one parameter to the `insertNum` method, `num` will be set the `None` (the default value) and will raise the exception.

If you don't want to change the order of the arguments, you can use this:

```
def insertNum(self, num, line=None):
    if line is None:
        raise Exception("Num not specified.")
    else:
        self.list.insert(num, line)
    return self.list
```

A simple demonstration for how default arguments work:

```
>>> def foo(bar, baz=None):
...     print(bar, baz)
...
>>> foo(1, 2)
1 2
>>> foo(2)
2 None
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about [exceptions and errors](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) 
But the main idea is that you catch errors and then you handle them the way you like.

```
try: 
 #do something 
except Exception as e:
 # error occured
 print("A wild error appeared")
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your function with another function that will have `try` and except` and there you could raise what ever error/exception you want.

```
def wrapper_func(self, num, line):
    try:
        self.insertNum(num, line)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("whatever you want")
```